# Disable a Multimedia Key on Keyboard

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, hardware

Okay, so I have a cheap Multimedia Keyboard that I used for a short while. Considering its price, I am surprised it last this long (1.2 years). But recently when I start Ubuntu, the Calculator key seems to stay pressed although in reality no one is pressing it. And soon after login, the Calculator app just keeps opening one after the other. Within 30 seconds, there are 150-180 calculator apps opened and it chokes my desktop.

I know it might be a hardware problem and I need to change the keyboard, but I was just wondering that is there a way to disable a key. So that even if the OS receives the input, it does nothing? I am just asking this out of curiosity, as I know there might not be a solution for this other than changing the keyboard.

Comment: Yes, most likely you can do it but first you have to find its keycode by running `xev` in a terminal.

Comment: The only thing of substance I can find is: `KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x1a1, subw 0x0, time 26973642, (1197,535), root:(1285,687),
    state 0x10, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
"
    XFilterEvent returns: False`

 Although, I must say I am not an expert on xev logs!